# Parsing a CSV file using MS Text Driver / CDatabase

Tags: c++

I have a CSV file that I am trying to process that looks similar to the one below. This format was is already in use within legacy software so unfortunately I can't change it. As you can see the file is separated into two sections- in this example one section for items, and one section for parts within those items.

```
ID,Description,Make,Model,Serial,Parts
200,Fridge,Samsung,S4450,SX05948596,1x34.4x22
354,Dishwasher,Bobs,BB45,BFDD34848,3x34.1x55.4x2
ENDITEMS
STARTPARTS
ID,Description,Price,Created
34,Bolt,4.33,08/05/15
22,Nut,1.20,10/10/12
ENDPARTS
```

I am currently trying to use the Microsoft text driver and `CDatabase`/`CRecordset` to parse the file, but am running into an issue. It seems the engine gets confused with some fields about what data type to use - specifically the fields where the first section and the second section use differing types.

For example, if I call `recordSet.GetFieldValue()` on index 1 (Description), that is fine and it parses it as a string as both section 1 and 2 use strings. If I were to call it on index 4 I run into issues - for the first section that index (Model) uses strings, but in the second section that index (Created) uses a date type. The results in the `GetFieldValue()` call returning null.

I have tried calling `CRecordSet.GetFieldValue(index, CDBVariant, SQL_C_CHAR)` to force it to read the index as a string, but I'm still getting a null returned. If possible I'd like to avoid having to chop up the file before parsing.

Now I'm fairly new to C++ still, so there may be some glaring errors here, but here is my test code (the `printType()` method just prints out the type and value of the CDBVarient):

```
CString fileDir = "C:\\";
CString fileName = "test.CSV";
CString conString; 
CString queryString;

conString.Format("DRIVER={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DSN='';DBQ=%s;", fileDir);
queryString.Format("SELECT * FROM [%s]", fileName);

CDatabase db;
CRecordset rs;
rs.m_pDatabase = &db;

db.OpenEx(conString);
if (rs.Open(AFX_DB_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE, queryString))
{
    int count = rs.GetODBCFieldCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        CODBCFieldInfo fieldInfo;
        rs.GetODBCFieldInfo(i, fieldInfo);

        CDBVariant varValue;
        rs.GetFieldValue(i, varValue, SQL_C_CHAR);

        std::cout << i << " " << fieldInfo.m_strName << ":\t";
        printType(&varValue);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use MS Text Driver? A standard C++ parsing program would not be hard to write supposing the strings don't contain the delimitor itself. See here: https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/204808/parsing-a-csv-file-separated-by-semicolons-

Comment: I suppose I don't have to - I was just hoping I was missing something small, like misusing `SQL_C_CHAR` in `GetFieldValue()`. Reading the docs I assumed SQL_C_CHAR did what I was after.

Comment: I suppose there is a way to do what you want, but this particular API does not seem to have a large users base, and after a superficial search the documentation looks to be sparse. There is a lot of online questions about simple text parsing, which should make the work easier for you.